# Icons and bars on desktop not showing

Tags: unity, 12.10, icons

I am using ubuntu 12.10 and today after i updated my software, when the computer restarted, the icons and menu bars on the desktop did not show. The a icons on the desktop itself still showed but nothing else (no launcer buttons, no time, nothing). 
Im not sure exactly what caused this. I could not find anything anywhere else. I tried the compiz ccsm unity thing but to no avail. It tells me that unity is running. I tried to unity --reset but I just get told that it is deprecated. Im not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

[How do I reset my Unity configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

The above might be a useful thread on how to reset unity in 12.10.

My apologies; this should probably be a comment not an answer but I don't have comment privileges yet.  If someone wants to edit this answer and convert to a comment I'd be delighted.